# Scheduling an asyncio coroutine from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I try to schedule an asyncio coroutine from another thread using `create_task()`. The problem is that the coroutine is not called, at least not in reasonable amount of time.

Is there are way to wake up the event loop or at least specify a shorter timeout?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import asyncio, threading

event_loop = None

@asyncio.coroutine
def coroutine():
    print("coroutine called")

def scheduler():
    print("scheduling...")
    event_loop.create_task(coroutine())
    threading.Timer(2, scheduler).start()

def main():
    global event_loop

    threading.Timer(2, scheduler).start()

    event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop)
    event_loop.run_forever()

main()
```

Output:

```
scheduling...
scheduling...
scheduling...
scheduling...
```

Comment: Have you tried `event_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(coroutine)` instead of `event_loop.create_task(coroutine())`?

Comment: @freakish thanks! Did not work straight away, but I've found a solution based on this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the documentation of [Task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task) "this class is not thread safe". So scheduling from another thread is not expected to work.

I found two solutions for this based on the answers and comments here.

1. @wind85 answer: directly replacing the `create_task` line call with `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coroutine(), event_loop)` call. Requires Python 3.5.1.
2. Use `call_soon_threadsafe` to schedule a callback, which then creates the task:

   ```
   def do_create_task():
       eventLoop.create_task(coroutine())

   def scheduler():
       eventLoop.call_soon_threadsafe(do_create_task)
   ```

Comment: anyway which version are you using?

Comment: Ahh, very interesting indeed. Good finding.

Comment: I had a similar problem and `run_coroutine_threadsafe()` worked.

Answer (score 3):

Here we go this shuold work. It's a port. Try it out since I have the latest version, I can't really assure you it will work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import concurrent.futures 
import threading, asyncio
from asyncio import coroutines, futures

def run_coroutine_threadsafe_my(coro, loop):
    """Submit a coroutine object to a given event loop.
        Return a concurrent.futures.Future to access the result.
    """
    if not coroutines.iscoroutine(coro):
        raise TypeError('A coroutine object is required')
    future = concurrent.futures.Future()

    def callback():
        try:
            futures._chain_future(asyncio.ensure_future(coro, loop=loop), future)
        except Exception as exc:
            if future.set_running_or_notify_cancel():
                future.set_exception(exc)
            raise

    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(callback)
    return future




event_loop = None

@asyncio.coroutine
async def coro():
    print("coroutine called")

def scheduler():
    print("scheduling...")
    run_coroutine_threadsafe_my(coro(),event_loop)
    threading.Timer(2, scheduler).start()

def main():
    global event_loop

    threading.Timer(2, scheduler).start()

    event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop)
    event_loop.run_forever()

main()
```

Comment: Thanks! That definitely works. However, it required Python 3.5.1, which is not installed on most computers.

Comment: I got `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_chain_future'` in Python 3.4.3 when running your updated code.

Comment: @kfx `run_coroutine_threadsafe` is available since asyncio 3.4.4. You can update using `pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/python/asyncio.git`