# Scheduling an asyncio coroutine from another thread without bunch of callbacks and synchronous waiting

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have to ask a clarification for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841222/scheduling-an-asyncio-coroutine-from-another-thread) question.

I have a coroutine `send` that sends a message. I want to schedule it in the `loop1` (which is running in thread 1) from the `loop2` (which is running in thread 2):

```
async def send_threadsafe(self, message, current_loop=loop2, dest_loop=loop1):
    future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
        send(message), loop=dest_loop
    )
```

The `future` returned by `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` is a `concurrent.futures.Future` and cannot be waited asynchronously.

So the question is: how do I properly await `future` and/or how should I schedule my `send` to get an awaitable object?

I know I can do:

```
async def send_threadsafe(...):
    future = ...
    result = await current_loop.run_in_executor(None, future.result)
```

But is there a way to do it without using another thread? Because `run_in_executor` will send `future.result` to a threadpool and I don't want to utilize that threadpool.

The reason I don't want to use `call_soon_threadsafe` is that it requires creating several callbacks. First, to schedule running `send` in `loop1`. Second, to run `send` in `loop1` and to schedule the third callback in `loop2`. Third, to set a result to a future that was created in the first callback (because asyncio futures are not threadsafe and I can't set result from `loop1`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `asyncio.wrap_future` to get an asyncio future from a concurrent future:

```
async def send_threadsafe(self, message, destination, *, loop=loop):
    concurrent = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
        send(message), loop=destination)
    return await asyncio.wrap_future(concurrent, loop=loop)
```

It is possible to achieve the same thing by implementing an asyncio executor:

```
from concurrent.futures import Executor

class AsyncioExecutor(Executor):

    def __init__(self, loop):
        self.loop = loop

    def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        coro = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, self.loop)
```

Example:

```
executor = AsyncioExecutor(remote_loop)
result = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, send, message)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems exactly what I was looking for! By the way, shouldn't `async def send_threadsafe()` in your first example be just `def send_threadsafe()`?

Comment: @Zelta Oops, it's fixed!