# Is there a way to manually switch on asyncio event loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want to use the event loop to monitor any inserting data into my asyncio.Queue(you can find its source code here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/asyncio/queues.py), but I run into some problems. Here is the following code:

```
import asyncio
import threading

async def recv(q):
    while True:
        msg = await q.get()
        print(msg)

async def checking_task():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

def loop_in_thread(loop,q):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    asyncio.ensure_future(recv(q))
    asyncio.ensure_future(insert(q))
    # asyncio.ensure_future(checking_task()) comment this out, and it will work as intended
    loop.run_forever()

async def insert(q):
    print('invoked')
    await q.put('hello')

q = asyncio.Queue() 
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
t = threading.Thread(target=loop_in_thread, args=(loop, q,))
t.start()
```

The program has started and we can see the following result

```
invoked
hello
-> print(asyncio.Task.all_tasks())
{<Task pending coro=<recv() running at C:/Users/costa/untitled3.py:39>
wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001E215DCFAC8>()]>>}
```

But now if we manually add data into `q` by using `q.put_nowait('test')`, we would get the following result:

```
q.put_nowait('test') # a non-async way to add data into queue
-> print(asyncio.Task.all_tasks())
{<Task pending coro=<recv() running at C:/Users/costa/untitled3.py:39>
 wait_for=<Future finished result=None>>}
```

As you can see, the future is already finished, yet we still haven't print out the newly added string `'test'`. In other words, `msg = await q.get()` is still waiting even though the Future related to q.get() is done and there are no other tasks running. This confuses me because in the official documentation(https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html), it says

> result = await future or result = yield from future – suspends the coroutine until the future is done, then returns the future’s result

It seemed that even though the Future is done, we still need some sort of `await` in other async function to make the event loop keep processing tasks.

I found a workaround to this problem, which is adding a `checking_task()`, and also add that coroutine into the event loop; then it will work as intended.

But adding a checking_task() coroutine is very costly for CPU since it just runs a while loop. I am wondering if there is some manual way for us to trigger that `await` event without using a async function. For example, something magical like

```
q.put_nowait('test')
loop.ok_you_can_start_running_other_pending_tasks()
```

Helps will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up with using

```
loop.call_soon_threadsafe(q.put_nowait, 'test')
```

and it will work as intended. After figure this out, I searched some information about . It turned out this post ([Scheduling an asyncio coroutine from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841222/scheduling-an-asyncio-coroutine-from-another-thread/37842263#comment63144818_37841222)) has the same problem. And @kfx's answer would also work, which is

```
loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.create_task, q.put('test'))
```

Notice asyncio.Queue.put() is a coroutine but asyncio.Queue.put_nowait() is a normal function.